# Separate button spacing equally and make responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#input-b6").fileinput({
            theme: "explorer",
            dropZoneEnabled: true,
            maxFileCount: 10,
            showDrag: false,
            showUploadedThumbs: true,
            hideThumbnailContent: true,
            browseLabel: "Attach",
            browseClass: "btn btn-primary buttonCss",
            uploadClass: "btn btn-primary buttonCss",
            removeClass: "btn btn-primary buttonCss",
            removeErrorClass: 'btn btn-primary buttonCss',
            showCaption: false,
            initialPreviewAsData: true,
            uploadUrl: 'null',
            uploadAsync: true,
            elPreviewContainer: '#banner_default',
            elPreviewImage: '#file-preview-thumbnails',
            msgSizeTooLarge: "This file is larger than {size} KB, please upload to UCR",
            layoutTemplates: {
                main2: '{preview}\n<div class="kv-upload-progress hide"></div>\n' +
                    '  <div class="input-group-btn">\n' +
                    '{browse}\n{upload}\n{remove}\n',
                actionDelete: '<button type="button" class="kv-file-remove {removeClass} removeBtnCss" title="{removeTitle}"{dataUrl}{dataKey}>{removeIcon}</button>\n',
                actions: '<div class="file-actions">\n' +
                    '<div class="file-footer-buttons">\n' +
                    '<div class="dropdown">\n' +
                    '<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">\n' +
                    '<span class="caret"></span></button>\n' +
                    '<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">\n' +
                    '<li><a href="#">{upload} Upload</a></li>\n' +
                    '<li><a href="#">{delete} Remove</a></li>\n' +
                    '<li><a href="#">{zoom} Preview</a></li>\n' +
                    '</ul>\n' +
                    '</div>\n' +
                    '</div>',
                actionZoom: '<button type="button" class="{zoomClass}" title="{zoomTitle}" onclick="openNewWindow(event)">{zoomIcon}</button>',
            },
        });
    })
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap 4.x is supported. You can also use the bootstrap css 3.3.x versions -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- if using RTL (Right-To-Left) orientation, load the RTL CSS file after fileinput.css by uncommenting below -->
<!-- link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/css/fileinput-rtl.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /-->
<!-- the font awesome icon library if using with `fas` theme (or Bootstrap 4.x). Note that default icons used in the plugin are glyphicons that are bundled only with Bootstrap 3.x. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- piexif.min.js is needed for auto orienting image files OR when restoring exif data in resized images and when you
    wish to resize images before upload. This must be loaded before fileinput.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/js/plugins/piexif.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- sortable.min.js is only needed if you wish to sort / rearrange files in initial preview.
    This must be loaded before fileinput.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/js/plugins/sortable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- purify.min.js is only needed if you wish to purify HTML content in your preview for
    HTML files. This must be loaded before fileinput.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/js/plugins/purify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- popper.min.js below is needed if you use bootstrap 4.x (for popover and tooltips). You can also use the bootstrap js
   3.3.x versions without popper.min.js. -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap.min.js below is needed if you wish to zoom and preview file content in a detail modal
    dialog. bootstrap 4.x is supported. You can also use the bootstrap js 3.3.x versions. -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- the main fileinput plugin file -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/themes/fas/theme.min.js"></script>

<div class="file-loading">
    <input id="input-b6" name="input-b6[]" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
</div>
```

Step 1)  Attach a file

Step 2)  Three button shows up on bottom.

Issue : How do I separate those button to fill the full page and make it responsive to screen resolution.

I am using a [Krajee File-input](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) to customize the buttons here, but it does not takes care of the spacing between buttons, thus I think custom css can be applied here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` for `.input-group-btn` class it will be work's or if you want to full width button use `.buttonCss{width:32%}`

```
.input-group-btn{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#input-b6").fileinput({
            theme: "explorer",
            dropZoneEnabled: true,
            maxFileCount: 10,
            showDrag: false,
            showUploadedThumbs: true,
            hideThumbnailContent: true,
            browseLabel: "Attach",
            browseClass: "btn btn-primary buttonCss",
            uploadClass: "btn btn-primary buttonCss",
            removeClass: "btn btn-primary buttonCss",
            removeErrorClass: 'btn btn-primary buttonCss',
            showCaption: false,
            initialPreviewAsData: true,
            uploadUrl: 'null',
            uploadAsync: true,
            elPreviewContainer: '#banner_default',
            elPreviewImage: '#file-preview-thumbnails',
            msgSizeTooLarge: "This file is larger than {size} KB, please upload to UCR",
            layoutTemplates: {
                main2: '{preview}\n<div class="kv-upload-progress hide"></div>\n' +
                    '  <div class="input-group-btn">\n' +
                    '{browse}\n{upload}\n{remove}\n',
                actionDelete: '<button type="button" class="kv-file-remove {removeClass} removeBtnCss" title="{removeTitle}"{dataUrl}{dataKey}>{removeIcon}</button>\n',
                actions: '<div class="file-actions">\n' +
                    '<div class="file-footer-buttons">\n' +
                    '<div class="dropdown">\n' +
                    '<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">\n' +
                    '<span class="caret"></span></button>\n' +
                    '<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">\n' +
                    '<li><a href="#">{upload} Upload</a></li>\n' +
                    '<li><a href="#">{delete} Remove</a></li>\n' +
                    '<li><a href="#">{zoom} Preview</a></li>\n' +
                    '</ul>\n' +
                    '</div>\n' +
                    '</div>',
                actionZoom: '<button type="button" class="{zoomClass}" title="{zoomTitle}" onclick="openNewWindow(event)">{zoomIcon}</button>',
            },
        });
    })
```

```css
.input-group-btn{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/*.buttonCss{width:32%}*/
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap 4.x is supported. You can also use the bootstrap css 3.3.x versions -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- if using RTL (Right-To-Left) orientation, load the RTL CSS file after fileinput.css by uncommenting below -->
<!-- link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/css/fileinput-rtl.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /-->
<!-- the font awesome icon library if using with `fas` theme (or Bootstrap 4.x). Note that default icons used in the plugin are glyphicons that are bundled only with Bootstrap 3.x. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- piexif.min.js is needed for auto orienting image files OR when restoring exif data in resized images and when you
    wish to resize images before upload. This must be loaded before fileinput.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/js/plugins/piexif.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- sortable.min.js is only needed if you wish to sort / rearrange files in initial preview.
    This must be loaded before fileinput.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/js/plugins/sortable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- purify.min.js is only needed if you wish to purify HTML content in your preview for
    HTML files. This must be loaded before fileinput.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/js/plugins/purify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- popper.min.js below is needed if you use bootstrap 4.x (for popover and tooltips). You can also use the bootstrap js
   3.3.x versions without popper.min.js. -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap.min.js below is needed if you wish to zoom and preview file content in a detail modal
    dialog. bootstrap 4.x is supported. You can also use the bootstrap js 3.3.x versions. -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- the main fileinput plugin file -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.1/themes/fas/theme.min.js"></script>

<div class="file-loading">
    <input id="input-b6" name="input-b6[]" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these

```
.input-group-btn {
    padding-left: 8%;
}

.btn-primary {
    width: 30%;
}
```